# Bind Zebra Browser Print to Vue 2.0

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

i am trying to integrate the Zebra BrowserPrint-1.0.4.js into Vue.
https://gist.github.com/robinsk/a667a490b7ef8192bbb9fcfc87f15757

Unfortunately I have a problem with saving the object.

```
mounted() {
    this.zebraDefaultDevice();
},
methods: {
    zebraDefaultDevice() {
        BrowserPrint.getDefaultDevice('printer', function (printer) {
            if ((printer != null) && (printer.connection != undefined)) {
                console.log(printer);
                this.selectedPrinter = printer;
            };
        });
    },
 }
```

The console.log function successfully gives me the printer I need.

```
t.Device {name: "29j164701943", deviceType: "printer", connection: "usb", uid: "29j164701943", version: 2, ...}
```

Afterwards I want to save the object with this.selectedPrinter. Unfortunately I get the following error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'selectedPrinter' of undefined

I also tried to save it into a global variable.

```
window.selectedPrinter
```

But when I try to read the variable outside the funciton it is null.

Maybe someone here can help me.

Comment: Greg, did you happen to figure out how to use BrowserPrint nicely within Vue.js? I'm attempting to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you have to access outside Vue, you should use app (vue variable that you assigned on Vue instance).selectedPrinter

That should work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).